# Calculate mode for each column in dataframe using lapply dplyr

Tags: r, function, dplyr, lapply

I'm trying to create a function that essentially gets me the MODE...or MODE-X (2nd-Xth most common value &  and the associated counts for each column in a data frame.

I can't figure out what I may be missing and I'm looking for some assistance?  I believe it has to do with the passing in of a variable into dplyr function.

```
library(tidyverse)


myfunct_get_mode = function(x, rank=1){

  mytable = dplyr::count(rlang::sym(x), sort = TRUE)
  names(mytable)= c('variable','counts')
  # return just the rank specified...such as mode or mode -1, etc
  result = table %>% dplyr::slice(rlang::sym(rank))
  return(result)
}

mtcars %>% lapply(. %>% (function(x) myfunct_get_mode(x, rank=2)))
```

Comment: Your function as it is here throws an error: "Only strings can be converted to symbols"

Comment: You need `!!` to evaluate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems with your function:

1. You function-call is not doing what you think. Check with `mtcars %>% lapply(. %>% (function(x) print(x)))` that actually your `x` is the whole column of `mtcars`. To get the names of the column apply the function to `names(mtcars)`. But then you also have to specify the dataframe you're working on.
2. To evaluate a symbol you get `sym` from you need to use `!!` in front of the `rlang::sym(x)`.
3. `rank` is not a variable name, thus no need for `rlang::sym` here.
4. `table` should be `mytable` in second to last line of your function.

So how could it work (although there are probably better ways):

```
myfunct_get_mode = function(df, x, rank=1){

  mytable = count(df, !!rlang::sym(x), sort = TRUE)
  names(mytable)= c('variable','counts')
  # return just the rank specified...such as mode or mode -1, etc
  result = mytable %>% slice(rank)
  return(result)
}

names(mtcars) %>% lapply(function(x) myfunct_get_mode(mtcars, x, rank=2))
```

Answer (score 0):

If we need this in a `list`, we can use `map`

```
f1 <- function(dat, rank = 1) {
        purrr::imap(dat, ~
                         dat %>%
                            count(!! rlang::sym(.y)) %>%
                            rename_all(~ c('variable', 'counts')) %>%
                            arrange(desc(counts)) %>%
                            slice(seq_len(rank))) #%>%
        #bind_cols - convert to a data.frame

}

f1(mtcars, 2)
```